# Getting a date x days back from a custom date in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a date key of type *20170501* which is in *YYYYmmdd* format. How can we get a date x days back from this date in Scala?

This is what I have in program

```
val runDate = 20170501
```

Now I want a date say 30 days back from this date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Scala/JVM/Java 8...

```
scala> import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> import java.time.format._
import java.time.format._

scala> val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
formatter: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)Value(MonthOfYear,2)Value(DayOfMonth,2)

scala> val runDate = 20170501
runDate: Int = 20170501

scala> val runDay = LocalDate.parse(runDate.toString, formatter)
runDay: java.time.LocalDate = 2017-05-01

scala> val runDayMinus30 = runDay.minusDays(30)
runDayMinus30: java.time.LocalDate = 2017-04-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [joda-time API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) with which has really good functions like

```
date.minusMonths
date.minusYear
date.minusDays
date.minusHours
date.minusMinutes
```

Here is simple example usinf JodaTIme API '

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
val dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val dt= "20170531"

val date = dtf.parseDateTime(dt)
println(date.minusDays(30))
```

Output:

```
2017-05-01T00:00:00.000+05:45
```

For this you need to use `udf` and create a `DateTime` object with your input format "`YYYYmmdd`" and do the operations.

Hope this helps!